# Get random sample of items from array, where items (which are also arrays) have things totaling to X

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

In an array such as:

```js
const myList = [['hi'], ['hello', 'bye'], ['ok'], ['blue', 'green', 'purple'], ['big', 'small', 'medium', 'orange', 'sky', 'ground', 'earth'], ['king', 'queen'], ['desk']]
```

How can I get a **random sample of items** in the array, but the total should be determined by input variable `size`.

So if the `size = 3`, an array would be returned such as

```js
[['desk'], ['king', 'queen']]
```

or maybe

```js
[['blue', 'green', 'purple']]
```

or even

```js
[['ok'], ['desk'], ['hi']]
```

If `size` is greater than the number of items in a flattened myList, then it should just return the maximum available items.

I haven't been able to figure this out, how can this be done?

Comment: If lodash has some way to accomplish this, I'd be interested in that solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to shuffle the array with a function like this one:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

shuffled_arr = shuffle(shuffled_arr); // assign and shuffle the data to this arr
```

and then pull 1 element until it reaches the maximum limit.

```
var shuffled_arr = shuffle(myList); // to shuffle the data
var results_arr = [];
var maximum_len = 3;
var current_len = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < shuffled_arr.length; i++) 
{
    if(current_len == maximum_len) break;
    if(current_len + shuffled_arr[i].length  <= maximum_len)
    {
        current_len+= shuffled_arr[i].length;
        results_arr.push(shuffled_arr[i]);
    }
}
```

In the end you have the array results_arr containing the X random strings.

You can check my fiddle over here - https://jsfiddle.net/2ds4vxqp/
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. However, looks like this flattens the array items, which are supposed to remain ordered in their arrays, as well as not allow repeats (it's currently allowing repeats). The `results_arr` should looks like this--> `[['desk'], ['king', 'queen']]`

Comment: @Raj Could they be split or they should remain all together? i.e. Could it have only 'king' from ['king', 'queen'] or it mush have all of them?

Comment: Let's call them tiny arrays which are within The Big array. The tiny arrays should remain in tact and untouched (and remain together). The shuffling should be only for the Big array.

Comment: @Raj I have updated my comment to include the Tiny arrays as a whole only. Please check it.
Have in mind that the array with results is still looking like [ ['hi'] , ['desk'], ['ok'] ]. I have just printed it in the div so the data inside can be seen.

Comment: thank you, this works. Something about your for-loop reminds me of `.reduce()`, though I wonder if it's not possible to solve with that since you can't break out of the loop with `.reduce()` when the length criteria is met.

Comment: @Raj I am sure there is a way to optimize it. I don't use javascript much lately and I`m surely missing something, but thats a good starting point to optimize it later. Cheers.